# Try to connect to hive via using pyhs2 in python | Error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudera'

Tags: python-3.x, hive

I am trying to connect to Hive from windows locally using python : below is the code that i used :

```
import pyhs2 as hive
DEFAULT_DB = 'default'
DEFAULT_SERVER = '10.37.40.1'
DEFAULT_PORT = 10000
DEFAULT_DOMAIN = 'PAM01-PRD01.IBM.COM'
u = "username"
s = "password"
# Build the Hive Connection
connection = hive.connect(host=DEFAULT_SERVER, port= DEFAULT_PORT, user=u + '@' + DEFAULT_DOMAIN, password=s)
# Hive query statement
statement = "select * from user_yuti.Temp_CredCard where pir_post_dt = '2014-05-01' limit 100"
cur = connection.cursor()

# Runs a Hive query and returns the result as a list of list
cur.execute(statement)
df = cur.fetchall()
```

and execute that script via cmd :

```
python hive-connection-test.py
```

But I am getting error -
[image]

Do guys have any idea that has happened here!! they is not package called cloudera in python package library, i have search for it.

Answer (score 3):

The error was caused by the `import` statement used in pyhs2. The import feature was supported by Python2 but not Python3. You can have a try using `Python2.7` instead of `Python3` (you are currently using).

pyhs2 is no longer maintained for years, so it's better to use other alternatives such as `PyHive` which is supported by Dropbox official.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I'm only going to half solve this questions as I'm only halfway through fixing it myself...

connections.py (located in Lib/site-packages/pyhs2/)has an import:

from cloudera.thrift_sasl import TSaslClientTransport

This is trying to import the thrift_sasl from the clouders subdirectory, so the syntax should actually be:

from .cloudera.thrift_sasl import TSaslClientTransport

You can go in and change it yourself, but then it turns out that thrift_sasl.py is trying cStringIO which is no longer available in Python 3.0... so trying to find a workaround for this now.

Hope this helps you along.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to switch to PyHive. Pyhs2 is no longer updated and doesn't support Python 3.

https://kyuubi.readthedocs.io/en/master/client/python/pyhive.html
https://pypi.org/project/PyHive/